# Getting OSError for using windll

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

I am new to using python and I am using a mac to run my program.I would like to use the ctype library to diplay a cursor on the screen. Unfortunately, I am getting an error and  I don't know how to fix it. Here is my code:

```
from ctypes import *

    h = windll.kernel32.GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)
    winddll.kernel32.SetConsoleCursorPosition(h, COORD(x, y))
```

And I keep getting that windll is not defined.
I have looked around a bit, and I found that I should do this:

```
    import ctypes
    libc = CDLL("libc.dylib.6")

        h = libc.windll.kernel32.GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)
        libc.winddll.kernel32.SetConsoleCursorPosition(h, COORD(x, y))
```

Unfortunately, I am getting an error saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "maze.py", line 20, in <module>
    libc = CDLL("libc.dylib.6")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py", line 369, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: dlopen(libc.dylib.6, 6): image not found
```

and I don't Know what to do.
Do note that I am using python 3.8.

Comment: windll is for Windows, not going to be useful on the Mac

Comment: Take a https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes thorough reading, and you'll see that things are much easier than they seem.

Comment: @MatsWichmann If you are talking about windll, then yes, I have changed it to cdll before. But I keep getting the same error. I keep getting Image not found.